# Ambiguity about -masu forms of ていく and てくる in informal speech

Tags: pronunciation, contractions

いく and くる are usually considered a pair of antonyms and ていく and てくる is a pair of common constructions from them. When conjugated to the masu form, the first one becomes ていきます and the second one becomes てきます. However in informal speech the first one can also be contracted to てぃきます which is not very different from the latter, just like ていく itself becomes てく. So how to tell which one the speaker is intended to say?

Comment: "first one can also be contracted to てぃきます" - I guess there's a typo here? Did you mean てきます?

Comment: Actually I meant that the い can be weakened (hence the small ぃ) in the speech (you can find similar usage for てぃる) and you're right if you omit it completely it becomes てきます, and it is not related to the ティ that is used to transcribe the sound of letter "T".

Comment: Ah got it, I didn't notice your い was smaller size!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on contexts. For example, when you are asked if you do something, これから やってきます will be interpreted as contraction from て行き, i.e "I'll do it from now on". On the other hand, it means "it will come soon" when you are asked when a certain climate comes.