# What's the structure of this lyric sentence? 「置いてかなくちゃいけないのかな」

Tags: song-lyrics, contractions, subsidiary-verbs

The sentence is:

> [明日]{あした}の[入]{い}り[口]{ぐち}に、[置]{お}いてかなくちゃいけないのかな？

Now I know the former part is "tomorrow, at the entrance (of our school)", and the following phrases:

おく　ーー　置いて, to put,

かな　ーー　is it so?

but I have no idea how to split the remaining of the latter part into pieces.

[置]{お}いて / **かなくちゃいけないの** / かな

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/30995/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57921/9831 -- "て[行]{い}く ⇒ てく, て[行]{い}き ⇒ てき"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 明日の入り口 probably translates literally (and somewhat poetically) to “tomorrow’s entrance.” Second, I think that the line breaks up into 置いて + か + なくちゃいけない + の + かな, with なくちゃいけない meaning “have to do” in this case. So the line translates roughly to, “I guess that we have to leave [these things] behind at the entrance to tomorrow.”

(I assume that this lyric is from 天使にふれたよ by HTT.)

Comment: Wow! Never thought `なくちゃいけない ` is inseparable. I searched this and learned it's even a JLPT-N5 grammer point. And yes it's from 天使にふれたよ. I'm learning some Japanese songs  currently.

Comment: Why not explain the か in 置いて + ***か*** + なくちゃいけない + の + かな ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the か is from ていく > てく

So
置いていく
置いてく
置いてかない
置いてかなくちゃいけない

Then consider the subject of the sentence, which is the previous two lines なじんだ制服と上履き、ホワイトボードの落書き

the whole sentence can be translated to “have to leave the familiar uniform and indoor shoes, and the scribble on the whiteboard (representing their time in high school) in front of the entrance of tomorrow, right?”

It’s a very delicate way to say however sad to leave, they need to advance to tomorrow.